# Beyond Compare 3 folder comparison silent error 100

Tags: windows, cmd, beyondcompare

I am trying to compare between 2 folders in silent mode and get the exit code

However when I run it I always get error 100

```
C:\Users\admin>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.com" /qc c:\Temp\source c:\Temp\destination
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Quick Compare (`/qc`) is only for files and does not work for folders.

Source: [Scooter Software](https://secure.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?13933-Beyond-Compare-3-folder-comparison-silent-error-100)

Answer (score 0):

According to _Beyond Compare [Command Line Reference](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?command_line_reference.html), the `/qc` switch means *quick comparison of two **files*** and syntax is `/qc=<type> | /quickcompare=<type>`. Performs a quick comparison of two files and sets the DOS error level on exit.  The specified type can be `size`, `crc`, or `binary`.  If a type is not specified, a rules-based comparison will be performed.  Error levels are documented in docs linked above.

First: Is a  `/qc` switch allowed for *folders* as well?

And if so, how to interpret the *If a type is not specified* condition? I'd say

- either omit the type `/qc=` and retain *eguals*,
- or omit the type `/qc`,
- or omit the switch at all?